# Upload Image from angular7 font end to nodejs server

Tags: node.js, file-upload, angular7

I am very new to MEAN and not able to send a file from HTML form to the server.

```
ts file
 fileData : File = null;
  onFileChange(image){
    this.fileData = image.target.files[0];
    console.log(this.fileData);
  }

  createMovie(){
    var finaldata = this.fileData;
    console.log(finaldata);
      this.service.createMovie(finaldata);
  }

service file
createMovie(data){
    console.log(data);
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('image', data, data.name);
    this.http.post(`${this.uri}/create-movie`, formdata).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  }
server file -> controller
exports.createMovie = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file); 
//displaying undefined in console
}
```

in console, I am getting undefined. Please help me

Comment: Can you post the router code?

Comment: Router.post('/create-movie', movieController.createMovie);

Comment: I believe you need a nodejs middlware for this [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Comment: yes I have imported multer, still, I am not able to fetch in a nodeJS server

Comment: Post that code too, please. Post it as part of your question

Comment: const multer = require('multer');
exports.createMovie = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
        const fileStorage = {
        storage: multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function(req, file, next){
                next(null, './image');
            },
        filename: function(req, file, next){
            console.log('File Started');
            console.log(file);
            console.log('File end');
        }
    }),
    };
    multer(fileStorage).single('photo')
//Folder creating in my project but nothing happen further lines of code.

Comment: You should post the code as part of your questions